# Find generating function For sequences

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, summation, generating-functions

Can anyone out here help?

The exercise says: "Find the generating function for each of the sequences below (the general term is given)"
Now, the question is how do you find one for those:
a) $U_n = 3$ if $n$ is a multiple of $2$, otherwise $U_n = 0$
b) $U_n = 5$ if $n$ is a multiple of $3$, otherwise $U_n = 1$

If someone could help out in at least how to get the summation formula here (for line b), it would be really helpful. For a), if I'm not wrong, the summation goes like  $\sum_{k = 0}^n 3 (z^2)^k$ and $S(z) = 3/(1-z^2)$. But how do you get that "1" to show when $k$ is not a multiple of $3$ on line b)? It should go something like $\sum 5 (z^3)^k$ , and then be $1z^k$, whenever $k$ is not a multiple of $3$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use the sum of two functions. One to generate the coefficients $1$ for all $n$, and one to adjust for the difference when $n \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$.

Comment: Yes, thanks, but how can mod 3 be represented mathematically?

Comment: What did you do for "mod 2" in the first part? How can you modify that idea to obtain "mod 3"?

Answer (score 1):

For (b) the sequence starting with $n=0$ is $5,1,1,5,1,1,5,1,1,\ldots$

You can take this to be the sum of the sequences $1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,\ldots$ and $4,0,0,4,0,0,4,0,0,\ldots$. Using the the same method you used for (a), the former is $\displaystyle \sum_{k = 0}^\infty z^k = \frac{1}{1-z}$, while the latter is $\displaystyle \sum_{k = 0}^\infty 4(z^3)^k = \frac{4}{1-z^3}$. Add these together and you get  $\dfrac{5+z+z^2}{1-z^3}$

Closer to your approach would be to see this as the sum of three sequences with generating functions $\dfrac{5}{1-z^3}$ and $\dfrac{z}{1-z^3}$ and $\dfrac{z^2}{1-z^3}$

Another route to the same result for (b) is to say that the terms repeat every three, so $U_{n+3}=U_n$ and thus the denominator of the generating function is $1-z^3$. Since the initial three terms are $5,1,1$, the corresponding numerator is $5+z+z^2$.